# Obtener numero de linea en donde se encuentra una palabra en un txt y a la vez otra palabra en otro txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, txt, read

```py
accounting_object = "lampara brillante"
position = ""

accounting_object_path_output = 'data_association/slot2/accounting_object_output.txt' #TEXTO 1
object_position_path_output = 'data_association/slot2/object_position_output.txt' #TEXTO 2

num_linea_data_field_1 = None
num_linea_data_field_3 = None
num_linea = None

validation_data_field_1 = False
validation_data_field_3 = False

with open(accounting_object_path,"r+") as f:
    lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]

    if (accounting_object not in lineas):
        pass

    elif (accounting_object in lineas):
        num_linea_data_field_1 = lineas.index(accounting_object)
        validation_data_field_1 = True

with open(object_position_path,"r+") as f:
    lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]

    if (position not in lineas):
        pass

    elif (position in lineas):
        num_linea_data_field_3 = lineas.index(position)
        validation_data_field_3 = True

if(validation_data_field_1 == True and validation_data_field_3 == True):
    if(num_linea_data_field_1 == num_linea_data_field_3):
    
    elif(num_linea_data_field_1 != num_linea_data_field_3):
```

Necesitaba encontrar el numero de la linea en la que en el primer archivo txt, este la palabra `"lampara brillante"` , y en el segundo archivo txt este `""`.

Suponiendo que en el primer txt esta:

```
lampara brillante
espejo
mouse
computadora
lampara brillante
laptop nueva
lampara brillante
lapicera violeta
```

y en el segundo txt se encuentre

```
sobre la estanteria
en la pared
sobre la mesa

sobre la mesa
sobre la mesa

en el escritorio
```

Solamente hay una linea de ambos txt que tiene en uno `"lampara brillante"` y en el otro una linea vacia `""`, y necesitaba hallar su valor en caso de que exista(en el caso del ejemplo si, pero podria no darse ninguna linea que contenga ambas coincidencias en los respectivos txt)

Comment: Este problema es una variante de tu otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/511796/7123 Creo que puedes adaptar la solución que allí te di sin mucho problema, no?

Comment: @abulafia lo pude adaptar, lo que complica en este caso es que puede haber mas de una coincidencia pero el objetivo es encontrar los indices donde en ambos se da la coincidencia con el input. Ahi puse como respuesta como lo arme al final

Answer (score 0):

Algo que intente y me funciono fue hacer una interseccion de las respectivas listas de lineas de los txt.
No tengo la certeza de que sea el proceso mas optimizado posible, pero a mi me sirvio, capaz a algun@ que lea la preg se ayude.

```py
accounting_object = "lampara brillante"
position = ""

accounting_object_path = 'data_association/slot2/accounting_object.txt' #TEXTO 1
object_position_path = 'data_association/slot2/object_position.txt' #TEXTO 2

with open(accounting_object_path,"r+") as f:
    lineas1 = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]

pos1 = [i for i in range(len(lineas1)) if lineas1[i] == accounting_object ]
print(pos1)

with open(object_position_path,"r+") as f:
    lineas2 = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]

pos2 = [i for i in range(len(lineas2)) if lineas2[i] == position ]
print(pos2)


#Interseccion de conjuntos ya implementada en python usando tablas hash
lineas_aux = list( set(pos1) & set(pos2) )
print(lineas_aux)

nro_linea = lineas_aux[0]
print(nro_linea)


#En python, si una lista o algun otro tipo de datos esta vacio o es NULL, se considera False
if not lineas_aux:
    match_coincidence = False

else:
    match_coincidence = True


if(match_coincidence == True):
    print("Las listas tienen elementos iguales en los mismos indices, osea en la misma linea de cada uno")
```